# Why are all elements in my array of objects null?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes. The first describes an item, and the seconds is built around an array of items of the first class.

I had learned that just creating an array of objects doesn't initialize them. So I put a for-loop in the constructor of the 2nd class to initialize all items. 
Yet when entering the clear() function, all elements of the list array are still null. Why is that?

```
class HneAnalogItem {
    String  description;
    String  unit;         
    float   value;

   HneAnalogItem(){}        
}

class HneAnalogInfo
{
    static final private int MAXANALOGINFOITEMS = 100;

    private HneAnalogItem[] list;

    HneAnalogInfo() {
        list = new HneAnalogItem[MAXANALOGINFOITEMS];
        for(HneAnalogItem item : list) {
            item = new HneAnalogItem();
        }

        clear();
    }

    void clear() {
        for(HneAnalogItem item : list) {
            item.description = "";
            item.unit = "";
            item.value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (HneAnalogItem item : list) {
    item = new HneAnalogItem();
}
```

This enhanced for loop doesn't initialize the array elements. It is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; list++) {
    HneAnalogItem item = list[i];
    item = new HneAnalogItem();
}
```

To initialize the array elements you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; list++) {
    list[i] = new HneAnalogItem();
}
```